# I am making a shut the box game

Tags: python

My game runs well but if the player inputs 'n' to end game an error comes up. Player enters 'n' if there is no combination of sum of the numbers on the board to equal the diceRoll. How can I stop this error?
Another thing is that if there is no more numbers left on the board then the player wins. I want it to end with 'You win' when there is no numbers left on the board. I was told to use
len(Board) == 0 but I do not know where and how.

```
import random

Board = set(range(1, 11))

def displayBoard(Board):
    for n in Board:
        print(n, end='|')
    print()

def playgame():

    print('Welcome! Here is your board, let\'s get started.')
    displayBoard(Board)

    while True:
        print('To begin, roll the pair of dice by typing \'r\' then press Enter''.')

        rollOne = input()
   
        if rollOne == 'r':
            diceRoll = random.randint(1, 6) + random.randint(1,6)
            print('The sum of your two rolls is ' + str(diceRoll) + '.  Now choose which \
                   numbers to remove from the board.')
    
        print('Here\'s the board again, you can type a single number, or multiple \
           numbers separated by a commma to remove them from the board. Then press Enter.')
        displayBoard(Board)
    
        newBoard = input()

        if newBoard == 'n':
            print('Game Over! You Lose!')

  
        numbers = [int(i) for i in newBoard.split(',')]
    
        if sum(numbers) != diceRoll:
            print("Your numbers don't add up to " + diceRoll)
        else:
            for n in numbers:
                if n not in Board:
                    print(n + " is not in board.")
                    return

            for i in numbers:
                Board.discard(i)
            print("Your new board is: ")
            displayBoard(Board)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    playgame()
```

Comment: Are you getting a `TypeError`?

Comment: The error I am getting is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 52, in <module>
    playgame()
  File "main.py", line 35, in playgame
    numbers = [int(i) for i in newBoard.split(',')]
  File "main.py", line 35, in <listcomp>
    numbers = [int(i) for i in newBoard.split(',')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'n'

Comment: The problem is that after the player enters "n", the loop just continues with `newBoard` set to `"n"`. So in the following lines, Python tries to call `numbers = [int(i) for i in newBoard.split(',')]` But `newBoard == 'n'` so `newBoard.split(',')` won't actually return a list of strings that can be parsed into numbers. You can break out of a loop with the `break` keyword.

Comment: Where should I place the break keyword.

Comment: At whatever place you want to break out of the loop. So in this case, I woud start by placing it in the if-statement where you check for `newBoard == 'n'`.

Comment: Thank you. Also for the second part that I am having issue with. Having the game end as win if there is nothing left on the board.

Comment: The game should stop once the board is empty? Then maybe you should consider changing the condition of the while loop. Instead of just looping unconditionally like you are right now, you could tie it to the state of the board instead.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry for asking so many questions, I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the following section of your code:

```
    print('Here\'s the board again, you can type a single number, or multiple \
       numbers separated by a commma to remove them from the board. Then press Enter.')
    displayBoard(Board)

    newBoard = input()

    if newBoard == 'n':
        print('Game Over! You Lose!')


    numbers = [int(i) for i in newBoard.split(',')]
```

When you type 'n', the `if newBoard == 'n':` is true so the message `'Game Over! You Lose!'` gets printed.

Then the next line of code `numbers = [int(i) for i in newBoard.split(',')]` runs. This tries to convert your input 'n' into integers. It fails with the error you see.

You can prevent this by simply adding a `return` statement in the if, after the print. This will end the `playgame` function.

```
    print('Here\'s the board again, you can type a single number, or multiple \
       numbers separated by a commma to remove them from the board. Then press Enter.')
    displayBoard(Board)

    newBoard = input()

    if newBoard == 'n':
        print('Game Over! You Lose!')
        return

    numbers = [int(i) for i in newBoard.split(',')]
```

I remember playing this game years ago with real dice - we called it flap dice.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to end the game with 'You Win' once there is no more numbers on the board. How would I do that

Comment: After your for loop that discards the numbers from `Board`, you could check if the board is empty `if len(Board) == 0:` print your message and return from the function

Comment: How would I test if my code works when there is nothing left on the board? The dice roll is random so how can I check that once there is nothing left on the board the game ends.